# Using a columns value in casting another column in a spark dataframe

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(100,2,1234.5678),(101,3,1234.5678)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1,(['id','dec','val']))

+---+---+---------+
| id|dec|      val|
+---+---+---------+
|100|  2|1234.5678|
|101|  3|1234.5678|
+---+---+---------+
```

Based on the value available in `dec` column, I want the casting to be done on the `val` column. Like if `dec = 2`, then I want the `val` to be cast to `DecimalType(7,2)`.

I tried to do the below, but it is not working:

```
 df.select(col('id'),col('dec'),col('val'),col('val').cast(DecimalType(7,col('dec'))).cast(StringType()).alias('modVal')).show()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 419, in cast
    jdt = spark._jsparkSession.parseDataType(dataType.json())
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 69, in json
    return json.dumps(self.jsonValue(),
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 225, in jsonValue
    return "decimal(%d,%d)" % (self.precision, self.scale)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not Column
```

The same works if I hard code the value to a specific number, which is straight forward.

```
df.select(col('id'),col('dec'),col('val'),col('val').cast(DecimalType(7,3)).cast(StringType()).alias('modVal')).show()

+---+---+---------+--------+
| id|dec|      val|  modVal|
+---+---+---------+--------+
|100|  2|1234.5678|1234.568|
|101|  3|1234.5678|1234.568|
+---+---+---------+--------+
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by user10281832, you can't have different data types in the same column.

Since the formatting is in focus you can convert the column to string type and then do the formatting. Since the number of decimals for each row is different, you can't use any inbuilt Spark functions but need to define a custom `UDF`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def format_val(num, prec):
    return "%0.*f" % (prec, num)

format_val_udf = udf(format_val, StringType())

df.withColumn('modVal', format_val_udf('val', 'dec'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Columns in Spark (or any relational system for that matter) have to be homogeneous - operation like this, where you `cast` each row to different type, is not only not supported, but also doesn't make much sense.

Comment: May be I am missing something here.But, please help me understand why casting of every row of a column in a spark data frame is not supported/invalid. I get that, casting a column based on other columns values may be an unpopular use case, but not sure why you would say the entire idea is not making any sense.

Comment: @vishnuram: The data type of all rows in the same column must be the same. However, if you are just after the formatting you could use a string in this case which would make the data type the same while allowing different number of decimals.

Comment: @shaido & user10281832 Thanks. Now I understand why there is a concern over datatype being heterogenous and have updated my commands in such a way to cast it to StringType() to add more clarity to my request